# CUDA: sum of data on a global memory variable

Tags: cuda, sum

I've launched a kernel with 2100 blocks and 4 threads per block.

Somewhat in this kernel all the threads have to execute a function, and put its result on an array (on global memory) into "threadIdx.x" position.

I surely know that, in this fase of the project, the function always returns 1.012086.
Now, I've written this code to do that sum:

```
currentErrors[threadIdx.x]=0;
for(i=0;i<gridDim.x;i++)
{
    if(i==blockIdx.x)
    {
        currentErrors[threadIdx.x]+=globalError(mynet,myoutput);
    }
}
```

But when the kernel ends all array's position has 1.012086 as value (instead 1.012086*2100).

Where I'm wrong?
Thanks for your helps!

Comment: This question and the previous questions you have asked strongly indicate that you are unclear on the very basics of CUDA. I think you should take a few steps back and read an introductory book on CUDA before attempting to continue with your project.

Comment: Before posting this question I have already read this guide about the reduction, but did not find anything for my specific case.
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf

Here there's no info about reduction between Cuda Blocks

Comment: Andrea, that means that you didn't understand the paper. Follow my advice and all will become clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute a final sum out of partial results of your blocks, I would suggest doing it the following way:

- Let every block write a partial result into a separate cell of a gridDim.x-sized array.
- Copy the array to host.
- Perform final sum on the host.

I assume each block has a lot to compute on its own, which would warrant the usage of CUDA in the first place.

In your current state --- I think there can be something wrong in your kernel. Seems to me that every block is summing all the data, returning a final result as if it was a partial result.

The loop you presented does not really make sense. For each block there is only one `i` which will do something. The code will be equivalent to simply writing:

```
currentErrors[threadIdx.x]=0;
currentErrors[threadIdx.x]+=globalError(mynet,myoutput);
```

save for some unpredictable scheduling differences.

Remember that blocks are *not* executed in sync. Each block can run before, during or after any other block.

---

Also:

- You may be interested in [parallel prefix sum algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum).
- You may want to check an [efficient CUDA implementation](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~billeter/pub/pp/) of the prefix sum.