# Summing up elements in array using managedCuda

Tags: cuda, managed-cuda

### Problem Description

I try to get a kernel summing up all elements of an array to work. The kernel is intended to be launched with 256 threads per block and an arbitary number of blocks. The length of the array passsed in as `a` is always a multiple of 512, in fact it is #blocks * 512. One block of the kernel should sum up 'its' 512 elements (256 threads can sum up 512 elements using this algorithm), storing the result in `out[blockIdx.x]`. The final summation over the values in `out` ,and therefore the results of the blocks, will be  done on the host. 
This kernel works fine for up to 6 blocks, meaning up to 3072 elements. But launching it with more than 6 blocks result in the first block calculating a strictly greater, wrong result than the other blocks (i. e. `out = {572, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512}`), this wrong result is reproducable, the wrong value is the same for multiple executions. 
I guess this means there is a structural error somewhere in my code, which has something to do with `blockIdx.x`, but the only use this is to calculate `blockStart`, and this seams to be a correct calculation, also for the first block. 
I verified if my host code computes the correct number of blocks for the kernel and passes in an array of correct size. That's not the problem. 
Of course I read a lot of similar questions here on stackoverflow, but none seems to describe my problem (See i. e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022920/cuda-sum-of-data-on-a-global-memory-variable?rq=1) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101539/cuda-reduction-basics?noredirect=1&lq=1)) 
The kernel is called via [managedCuda](https://kunzmi.github.io/managedCuda/) (C#), I don't know if this might be a problem.

### Hardware

I use a MX150 with the follwing specifications:

- Revision Number: 6.1
- Total global memory: 2147483648
- Total shared memory per block: 49152
- Total registers per block: 65536
- Warp size: 32
- Max Threads per block: 1024
- Max Blocks: 2147483648
- Number of multiprocessors: 3

### Code

#### Kernel

```
__global__ void Vector_Reduce_As_Sum_Kernel(float* out, float* a)
{   
int tid = threadIdx.x;
int blockStart = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x * 2;
int i = tid + blockStart;

int leftSumElementIdx =  blockStart + tid * 2;

a[i] = a[leftSumElementIdx] + a[leftSumElementIdx + 1];

__syncthreads();

if (tid < 128) 
{
    a[i] = a[leftSumElementIdx] + a[leftSumElementIdx + 1];
}

__syncthreads();

if(tid < 64)
{
    a[i] = a[leftSumElementIdx] + a[leftSumElementIdx + 1];
}

__syncthreads();

if (tid < 32)
{
    a[i] = a[leftSumElementIdx] + a[leftSumElementIdx + 1];
}

__syncthreads();

if (tid < 16)
{
    a[i] = a[leftSumElementIdx] + a[leftSumElementIdx + 1];
}

__syncthreads();

if (tid < 8)
{
    a[i] = a[leftSumElementIdx] + a[leftSumElementIdx + 1];
}

__syncthreads();

if (tid < 4)
{
    a[i] = a[leftSumElementIdx] + a[leftSumElementIdx + 1];
}

__syncthreads();

if (tid < 2)
{
    a[i] = a[leftSumElementIdx] + a[leftSumElementIdx + 1];
}

__syncthreads();

if (tid == 0)
{
    out[blockIdx.x] = a[blockStart] + a[blockStart + 1];
}
}
```

#### Kernel Invocation

```
//Get the cuda kernel
//PathToPtx and MangledKernelName must be replaced
CudaContext cntxt = new CudaContext();
CUmodule module = cntxt.LoadModule("pathToPtx");    
CudaKernel vectorReduceAsSumKernel = new CudaKernel("MangledKernelName", module, cntxt);

//Get an array to reduce
float[] array = new float[4096];
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = 1;
}

//Calculate execution info for the kernel
int threadsPerBlock = 256;
int numOfBlocks = array.Length / (threadsPerBlock * 2);

//Memory on the device
CudaDeviceVariable<float> m_d = array;
CudaDeviceVariable<float> out_d = new CudaDeviceVariable<float>(numOfBlocks);

//Give the kernel necessary execution info
vectorReduceAsSumKernel.BlockDimensions = threadsPerBlock;
vectorReduceAsSumKernel.GridDimensions = numOfBlocks;

//Run the kernel on the device
vectorReduceAsSumKernel.Run(out_d.DevicePointer, m_d.DevicePointer);

//Fetch the result
float[] out_h = out_d;

//Sum up the partial sums on the cpu
float sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < out_h.Length; i++)
{
    sum += out_h[i];
}

//Verify the correctness
if(sum != 4096)
{
    throw new Exception("Thats the wrong result!");
}
```

**Update:**

The very helpfull and only answer did address all my problems. Thank you! The problem was an unforeseen race condition.

**Important Hint:**

In the comments the author of managedCuda pointed out all NPPs methods are indeed already implmented in managedCuda (`using ManagedCuda.NPP.NPPsExtensions;`). I wasn't aware of that, and i guess so are many people reading ths question.

Comment: Oh, and why was this downvoted? I really tried to stress the generality of the problem, checked if there already is an answer, made my question clear, and yes, my mind is open to all answers.

Comment: Questions asking "why isn't this code working?" are supposed to include a [mcve]  See item 1  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  What you have shown is incomplete.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will edit my question. I thought it might be too much code, but if the guidelines ask me to do so...

Comment: In case that this might be of interest, just wanted to add the hint that managedCuda implements all NPPs functions as extensions to CudaDeviceVariable: `using ManagedCuda.NPP.NPPsExtensions;` and `m_d.Sum(out_d, tempBuffer);` avoids the self written kernel.

Comment: That's amazing, i wasn't aware of that. Will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly incorporating into your code the idea that each block will process 512 elements out of your total array.  According to my testing, you need to make at least 2 changes to fix this:

1. In the kernel, you have incorrectly calculated the starting point for each block:

   ```
   int blockStart = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
   ```

   since `blockDim.x` is 256, but each block processes 512 elements, you must multiply this by 2.  (the multiplication by 2 in your calculation of `leftSumElementIdx` doesn't take care of this -- since it is only multiplying `tid`).
2. In your host code, your number of blocks calculation is incorrect:

   ```
   vectorReduceAsSumKernel.GridDimensions = array.Length / threadsPerBlock;
   ```

   for a value of 2048 for `array.Length` and a value of 256 for `threadsPerBlock`, this creates 8 blocks.  But as you already indicate, your intention is to launch for blocks (2048/512).  So you need to multiply the denominator by 2:

   ```
   vectorReduceAsSumKernel.GridDimensions = array.Length / (2*threadsPerBlock);
   ```

In addition, your reduction sweep pattern is broken.  It is warp-execution-order dependent, to give the proper result, and CUDA does not specify a warp execution order.

To see why, let's take a simple example.  Let's consider just a single threadblock, with a starting point of the array being all 1, just as you have initialized it.

Now, warp 0 consists of threads 0-31.  Your reduction sweep operation is like this:

```
a[i] = a[leftSumElementIdx] + a[leftSumElementIdx + 1];
```

So each thread in warp 0 will collect two other values and add them, and store them.  Thread 31 will take the values `a[62]` and `a[63]` and add them together.  If the values of `a[62]` and `a[63]` are still 1, as initialized, then this will work as expected.  But the values of `a[62]` and `a[63]` **are written to** by warp 1, consisting of threads 32-63.  So if warp 1 executes before warp 0 (perfectly legal), then you will get a different result.  This is a global memory *race condition*.  It is arising due to the fact that your input array is both the source and destination of your intermediate results, and `__syncthreads()` will not sort this out for you.  It doesn't force warps to execute in any particular order.

One possible solution is to fix your sweep pattern.  On any given reduction cycle, let's have a sweep pattern where each thread writes and reads values that are not touched by any other thread during that cycle.  The following adaptation of your kernel code accomplishes that:

```
__global__ void Vector_Reduce_As_Sum_Kernel(float* out, float* a)
{
  int tid = threadIdx.x;
  int blockStart = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x * 2;
  int i = tid + blockStart;

  for (int j = blockDim.x; j > 0; j>>=1){
    if (tid < j)
      a[i] += a[i+j];

    __syncthreads();}

  if (tid == 0)
  {
    out[blockIdx.x] = a[i];
  }
}
```

For general purpose reductions, this is still a very slow method.  This [tutorial](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) covers how to write faster reductions.  And, as already pointed out, managedCuda may have methods to avoid writing a kernel at all.

Comment: Thanks for ponting out these mistakes. I fixed the first one - it fixed my code. The second one was only an issue on the code for SO. Sorry for wasting your time with such a stupid question, should have seen that by myself.

Comment: Fixing the first error only fixed my code for up to 6 blocks. But adding a seventh block causes the same problem as previously the fourtht block.

Comment: Yes, there was another issue that I missed.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Of course...when i made sketches of the algorithm i did always draw the next step into a new array. Thats why i didn't realize this. Thank you for all your help. Works now.